# How to save toggle state (React/Headless UI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, headless-ui

I've imported a Switch/Toggle component from HeadlessUI (https://headlessui.com/react/switch) to my NextJS app but I'm having some **trouble passing it's state (true/false) to the parent component.**

**When I try to replace onChange={setEnabled} or checked={enabled} by anything else, the toggle stops switching.** Therefore I can't replace it by props.setEnabled nor by a function because **even if I don't get any error, they don't get executed.**

**Here's a screen recording** hosted on Loom demonstrating my issue: https://www.loom.com/share/dac2ffa6060a48729c79c89e1524aca4

Thank you for your help ! Let me know if you need additional info.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Switch } from "@headlessui/react";

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

export default function Toggle(props) {
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState();


    // I TRIED TO PASS THIS FUNCTION TO onChange BUT IT DOESN'T WORK
  // const handleToggleState = () => {
  
  //   function switchToggle(){
  //   if (enabled == true) {
  //     setEnabled(false);
  //   } else {
  //     setEnabled(true);
  //   }
  // }}


  return (
    <Switch
      checked={enabled}
      onChange={setEnabled}
      className={classNames(
        enabled ? "bg-indigo-600" : "bg-gray-200",
        "relative inline-flex flex-shrink-0 h-5 w-11 border-2 border-transparent rounded-full cursor-pointer transition-colors ease-in-out duration-200 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
      )}
    >
      <span className="sr-only">Use setting</span>
      <span
        aria-hidden="true"
        className={classNames(
          enabled ? "translate-x-5" : "translate-x-0",
          "pointer-events-none inline-block h-4 w-4 rounded-full bg-white shadow transform ring-0 transition ease-in-out duration-200"
        )}
      />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Comment: all the `handleToggleState` function does is create another function, it doesnt do anything else

Comment: So what should I do ?
As you can see in the video, I tried multiple things and nothing seems to work. @ChrisLi

Comment: Have you tried using `onChange={() => setEnabled(val => !val)}`?

Comment: Using setEnabled always works and so this syntax also works. It's the only thing that works. But it's not solving my problem.

My issue is that I can't access this data in the parent component by either using props.setEnabled or by calling any another function that would do multiple things. @juliomalves

Comment: Of course you can - my suggestion passes a new function to `onChange`. If you want to declare and pass the function in the parent of `Toggle`, then create the `useState` there, define a function like the above, e.g. `const handleEnable () => setEnabled(val => !val)`, then pass the function to `Toggle`, e.g. `<Toggle handleEnable={handleEnable} >`. Then on the `Switch` component set `onChange={props.handleEnable}`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I just realized that my code was actually working, the problem was that the CSS was linked to the "enabled" const that was in the child component instead of being props.enabled.